# Can you hide your game info on steam without appearing offline?

Tags: steam

I want to not let people see any of the information about the server I'm playing on (to prevent things like DDoS attacks during a tournament) but it seems the only way to do that is to appear offline, but if I appear offline I can't be messaged on steam to organise things with the other players/organisers of the event. Is there a way to hide all the server information whilst remaining online and contactable?

Comment: Pro players just go offline. [source: Katowice 2015]

Comment: I know, I'm asking on behald of pro players who don't want to go offline because they want to be able to communicate with us over steam. We're using discord to communicate more broadly now anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your profile status is set to private, you can remain online, chat, etc., and not have people join your games.

To do this, log into Steam, then hover over your username at the top,  click `Profile` > `Edit Profile` > `My Privacy Settings` (on the right) > and set `Profile Status` to `Private`.

**Sources**

- My profile page (`http://steamcommunity.com/id/[my public
  id]/edit/settings`)
- Experience: I have a friend who keeps his account private